# Capturing Websocket Data Using Python

Tags: python, websocket

Im new to python development and i have a small project to capture a websocket data from python,
here is the code that i attempted

```
import websockets
import asyncio


async def listen():
    url = "wss://socket.asiacontrol.com/first/ef8e9e63-4a64-468c-aba3-8afa4b97ed09"

    async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
        while True:
            msg = await ws.recv()
            print(msg)


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(listen())
```

it is successfully run for several minutes, with output

```
C:\Users\ursab\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/ursab/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py 
{"msg":"Authorized"}
{"wssname":"inf-wssn-dockeraws_","id":1018153040,"tp":2,"msg":"UpdatingTrx","ust":{"by":"nicole","on":1690162178042,"tst":-1},"isupdate":true}
{"data":{"agcd":"xcgkul100","id":1018153040,"tp":2,"status":-1,"dscs":3,"dsst":22,"idsub":89611520,"rcdtm":"24-07-2023 08:26:32"},"msg":"UpdatedTrx"}
{"idag":89468785,"agcd":"xcgkul100","trx":{"id":1018155315,"amt":704,"rcdtm":"24-07-2023 08:29:51","st":0,"ststr":"Pending","tp":2,"tpstr":"Withdraw","idus":113842366,"note":"-","trxNote":"-","refNo":"WD-113842366-202307240829","is_validate":0,"usb":{"id":96122599,"idmb":12,"bank":"Dana","bcode":"dana","accnm":"AAS ASROPAH","accno":"081572461702"},"un":"xcgkul100@corporation","usnn":"corporation","admfee":0,"admperc":0,"ttldp":1,"tr_color":"#FFFFFF"},"msg":"NewTrx"}
```

The code works fine for a several minutes and after that these exception thrown,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ursab\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 1302, in close_connection
    await self.transfer_data_task
  File "C:\Users\ursab\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 959, in transfer_data
    message = await self.read_message()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ursab\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 1029, in read_message
    frame = await self.read_data_frame(max_size=self.max_size)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ursab\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 1104, in read_data_frame
    frame = await self.read_frame(max_size)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ursab\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 1161, in read_frame
    frame = await Frame.read(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ursab\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\framing.py", line 68, in read
    data = await reader(2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ursab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\streams.py", line 729, in readexactly
    await self._wait_for_data('readexactly')
  File "C:\Users\ursab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\streams.py", line 522, in _wait_for_data
    await self._waiter
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ursab\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(listen())
  File "C:\Users\ursab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ursab\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 15, in listen
    msg = await ws.recv()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ursab\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 568, in recv
    await self.ensure_open()
  File "C:\Users\ursab\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 944, in ensure_open
    raise self.connection_closed_exc()
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: sent 1011 (unexpected error) keepalive ping timeout; no close frame received

Process finished with exit code 1
```

i dont know whats wrong, is this something related to keep alive ?
any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried these code and works only for several minutes and i expect that the code is running until it is terminated.